# Defining setter in model in context of has_many-belongs_to assoication in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-and-belongs-to-many, setter

Now I am teaching myself with the book "Rails 4 in action", and got stuck at some point. Let me describe my problem.

I have 3 models that are a state, a ticket and a comment. Both the ticket and the comment belong to the state. The comment belongs to the ticket, and the ticket has many comments. Then here is the comment model class below.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :previous_state, class_name: "State"

  before_create :set_previous_state
  after_create :set_ticket_state

  private

    def set_previous_state
      self.previous_state = ticket.state
    end

    def set_ticket_state
      ticket.state = state
      ticket.save!
    end
end
```

What I don't understand is why the following belongs_to statement is needed here.

```
belongs_to :previous_state, class_name: "State"
```

The column previous_state_id is already in the comments table, so I am assuming the code 'self.previous_state = ticket.state' in the set_previous_state method can be used without the above belongs_to statement.

[image: The comments table]

[image: The states table]

Could you enlighten me on this?
The image below what happens when I remove the 'belongs_to :previous_state, class_name: "State"'.

[image: No method error when removing the belongs_to statement]

Comment: Are you settings reference for previous_state_id to table states?

Comment: Yes, Would you look at the post again? I updated it adding an image of the states table.

Comment: what happens if you remove ```belongs_to :previous_state, class_name: "State"``` ?

Comment: As you can see in the states table, I am trying to make the comments table reference to the states table.

Comment: What happens when removing it, NoMethodError occurs. I added the error image on the post.

Comment: Yes, correctly. The problem at that. ```self.previous_state = ticket.state``` Because you have a reference from comment to state via previous_state_id. It means when you call self.previous_state, you must be set the relationship for comment and previous_state

Comment: Thank you sir. But what does it mean exactly to call `self.previous_state`? What I assume now is that the column `previous_state_id` is already in the comments table, so I thought calling it `self.previous_state` without setting relationship is possible.

Comment: If you not set relationship, You cant call ```self.previous_state``` but you can call by another way. Maybe: ```State.find(self.previous_state_id)```

Comment: It seems `self.previous_state_id = ticket.state` also works. I think rails cleverly takes care of this. You answer helps me a lot.